# Convert time series

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a Python 2.7 `ndarray` (time series value) in a format of:

```
18631    23:18
```

I am struggling to find a simple way to convert this to an int as similar with `total_seconds()`

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain the significance of the `18631`?

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what the exact problem is asking for. I'm assuming you want to convert the `23:18` to seconds elapsed for the day?

```
import numpy as np

time_stamp = np.array([18631, "23:18"])
time_day = time_stamp[1]
h, m = [int(i) for i in time_day.split(":")]
print "Seconds elapsed for day = %d" % (3600*h + 60*m)
```